# perforce - extending p4 interchanges output to include changes integrated to source

Tags: perforce

We have a codeline that flows from trunk -> A -> B and we have people working in either A directly or in trunk which we merge down for public release via branch B.

Now I have a requirement to provide a list of changes that are in branch A, and not yet in branch B, so that we can pass to the QA team. For that, I run this command:

```
p4 interchanges -b integrate_branch_a_to_branch_b
```

However we've got changes there which have been integrated from trunk to A in one big changelist (but are actually made up of multiple submitted changelists). I need these to be included in my change notes. According to the Perforce documentation (https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/cmdref/p4_changes.html), the p4 changes command should do this if I pass the -i flag.

So what I have is a changelist numbered 12345 that was submitted to branch A (as an integrate from trunk). I want to expand that to list every changelist that was submitted to trunk, exactly as p4 interchanges would have shown me had I run it to preview what was going across in CL #12345.

I tried this command:

```
p4 changes -i -s submitted //myproject/branches/a/...@12345,12345
```

Which I think should have worked and given me something like this:

```
Change 12345 on 2015/10/30 by user@host 'trunk -> a'
Change 12344 on 2015/10/29 by user@host 'fixed bug two'
Change 12343 on 2015/10/29 by user@host 'fixed bug one'
```

But it gives me thousands of changes, most of which are outside of the range of changelists I've asked for, dating even further back than the first revision of any branch for this project - from when we integrated some shared library code from //otherproject/ to //myproject/. If I remove the "-i" flag, it works as I'd expect - it lists only changelist 12345.

Is it just a bug in this command, or is my syntax wrong? I can't seem to figure out a way to get what I need. I can probably dig back and find the last integration from trunk -> A and manually filter older changelists in my script, of course - but it would be easier if I didn't have to.

P4 Server version string is:  P4D/LINUX26X86_64/2014.2/962050 (2014/11/13)

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly, you are looking for all changes to be integrated from A -> B, but for any integrates from trunk -> A you want to see the individual changes not the single integration change?

While you cannot do this in a single expression, you can run two interchanges commands:

```
 p4 interchanges -b integrate_branch_a_to_branch_b  
 p4 interchanges -b integrate_trunk_to_branch_b
```

The second command will list all the individual changes in the trunk not yet integrated into branch B.

You will have some duplicates here, since the first command (A->B) will also show you the integration-only changes, but this should be easy to filter out.

Comment: Yes, your summary of what I want is correct. 

The problem I have is that trunk already has more changes submitted (that haven't been integrated to A, and that I am not interested in). So if I do the 2nd p4 interchanges there it's going to list changes that are submitted to trunk but which I don't intend to integrate to B anyway. Right? I'd really need to be able to run something like this:

`code` p4 interchanges -b integrate_trunk_to_branch_b @12344.

Comment: That command exists in the way you want it, please see my last answer above.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with:

```
- p4 interchanges -b integrate_branch_a_to_branch_b
- for each change:
    - p4 describe -s change, and figure out if there were any "branch" 
    or "integrate" actions
    - if no, then it's a direct edit and we are interested in it
    - if yes, then it's an integration from our source branch (trunk) and 
    we need to find the original changelists
    - for each change where yes:
        - p4 integrate -n //myproject/branches/a/...@change,change //myproject/branches/b/....
        - if output (stderr) contains 'already integrated' then ignore
        because it has already been integrated
        - else run p4 changes -s submitted -i -l /myproject/branches/a/...
        (this will give us a list of all changelists that made up the
        single integrate changelist 12345 that I described above)
        - for each change there:
            - run p4 integrate -n //myproject/branches/trunk/...@change,change /myproject/branches/b/...
            - if output (stderr) contains 'already integrated' then ignore 
            because it has already been integrated
            - else run p4 describe -s change and check if standard output
            contains //myproject/branches/trunk - if not then it was an integrate
            *to* trunk from somewhere else and we don't care about it 
            (this is intended to fix the - issue where p4 changes goes
            beyond the first revision that I am interested in)
```

First run p4 interchanges to get the list of unintegrated changes to work with. Then for each change there we process to either find that #1) it's really unintegrated and #2) it's not too old for our requirements.

I also know a changelist where we'd last run a full QA test, so can break early on the bottom loop when we start to read changes that are older than those I am interested in (working around the p4 changes -i issue).

Seems to work. Extremely cumbersome, though.

Answer (score 0):

The command you are looking for exists:

```
p4 interchanges -b integrate_trunk_to_branch_b @12345
```

The documentation is a bit convoluted I know:

```
interchanges -- Report changes not yet integrated

p4 interchanges [options] fromFile[revRange] toFile
p4 interchanges [options] -b branch [toFile[revRange] ...]
p4 interchanges [options] -b branch -s fromFile[revRange] [toFile ...]
p4 interchanges [options] -S stream [-P parent] [file[revRange] ...]
```

The toFile bit refers the target but the revRange refers to the source, so you can simply specify an upper boundary in your command.

Are you using a scripting language like Python or Ruby for your script?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Python (though not yet P4Python).

I tried what you suggested but I don't quite understand how it's meant to work. Need to post more details separately due to character limit.

Comment: A change 740004 has just gone into trunk, and it has been merged to branch A in changelist 740005 because it's an emergency fix. If I run _p4 interchanges integrate_branch_a_to_branch_b_ it is going to give me changelist 740005 since I haven't integrated that to branch B. I'd expect this, of course.

But then in step 2 I'd run _p4 interchanges -b integrate_trunk_to_branch_b @740005_, but it's going to give me changelist 740004 but I don't have any reasonable way to filter it out since nothing tells me that it's a duplicate. Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe I don't get your requirements yet. If you are happy with integration only changes (740005) and just want to add changes in trunk not yet in A, then add 'interchanges trunk->A' to 'interchanges A->B'. I thought you wanted to see the individual changes in the trunk as well.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is I want both (because sometimes there is a direct edit in A, but sometimes it's an integration from trunk and can contain multiple changes). Maybe I'm not explaining it very well.

Comment: I could branch trunk -> C @12345 and then combine p4 interchanges with A -> B with C -> B. Since any direct edits made in A would have been pushed back to trunk, that would get rid of the duplicates in that direction, and leave only changes in trunk but not in A, going into C. So comparing A with B and then C with B should give me the total changes from both sources.